# I want to start archiving the wal files at different location?

Tags: postgresql

I want to start archiving wal files at different locations I set the archive_wal = on but I am confused about how to set the archive command values in postgresql.conf file
please show me the proper example of what %f and %p means. give me a dummy example.

Comment: If you don't understand the docs, please describe what about them you are confused about, quoting the relevant confusing sections.

Comment: #archive_command = ''           # command to use to archive a logfile segment
                                # placeholders: %p = path of file to archive
                                #               %f = file name only
                                # e.g. 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archivedir/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archivedir/%f'   how to put value in this archive
_command parameter in postgresql.conf